# EntityField in persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod

There is data family `EntityField ent typ` which is defined in class `PersistEntity ent`.
I should use it in `Filters`, `SelectOpts` and so on. But I can't find a way to get it at runtime. I need something like

```
data SomeEF e = forall typ. SomeEF { unSomeEF :: EntityField e typ }
```

and

```
getEntityFields :: PersistEntity e => e -> [SomeEF]
```

I need it for instance to make possibility for user define filters or orders dynamically.

Is there exists somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such function right now. You could write a new TH function that would generate it, or theoretically it could be achieved via `Generic` deriving, I'm not certain.

Comment: Probably it is better (at least more simple) do in persistent? What do you think? I can trying to do it someday. Instance for Eq,Show,Read is also required for me.